# AWS gremlin - show edge label on graph

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, graph-notebook

I want to get a graph with the label edge. How can do it?

I use this my graph_notebook and magic cell code like this, and standard visualization options:

%%gremlin
g.V().out().path()

but it doesn't show any edge label or property. Thank you

Tried to use -d and -de options(though need a label, not a property), it was no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path needs to include the edge for its labels and properties to be available in the visualization. As a start, try using

```
%%gremlin 
g.V().outE().inV().
  path().
    by(elementMap())
```